# adding rows to data table using for loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop, division

I am playing with some basic R functions and am trying to create a table that includes the Remainder and Quotient for the numbers 1:20
First I created this function:

```
Find_Remains = function(number, divisor){
              Remainder = number%%divisor
              Quotient = number%/%divisor
              a = c(number, divisor, Remainder, Quotient)
              return(a)
}
```

I add a blank table

```
final.data.frame = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 1, ncol = 4))
```

Then I created this for loop

```
for(i in c(1:20)){
    b[i] = Find_Remains(i,5)
    final.data.frame = rbind(b[i])
}
```

the error I get is:

```
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos on initializing `final.data.frame` (although initializing it with 20 rows would have been better I think). Having done that you don't need to use `rbind`, you can simply replace each row of the dataframe in every loop run. Here's what you need -

```
Find_Remains = function(number, divisor) {
              Remainder = number%%divisor
              Quotient = number%/%divisor
              a = c(number, divisor, Remainder, Quotient)
              return(a)
}

final.data.frame = data.frame(matrix(NA, nrow = 20, ncol = 4))

for(i in 1:20) {
  final.data.frame[i, ] = Find_Remains(i,5)
}

> final.data.frame
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1  5  1  0
2   2  5  2  0
3   3  5  3  0
4   4  5  4  0
5   5  5  0  1
6   6  5  1  1
7   7  5  2  1
8   8  5  3  1
9   9  5  4  1
10 10  5  0  2
11 11  5  1  2
12 12  5  2  2
13 13  5  3  2
14 14  5  4  2
15 15  5  0  3
16 16  5  1  3
17 17  5  2  3
18 18  5  3  3
19 19  5  4  3
20 20  5  0  4
```

Comment: thanks!  That worked!  I tried the code with final.data.frame[i] but that didn't work.  the code final.data.frame[i,] allows it to be placed in a row.

Comment: Happy to help! If this answers your question then consider marking it correct using the tick mark at top left.